Help with understanding the calculation of an expected sum
A box with $N$ balls numbered from $1$ to $N$. We take $n$ balls out with no returning. I need help with understanding the calculation of their expected sum.
So let's say that $S_n$ is the sum of the numbers written on the balls we took out.
For every $1\leq i \leq n$, $X_i$ is the number written on the $i$th ball we took out of the box. So, we get: $$S_n = X_1 + \ldots + X_n.$$
We need $\mathbb{E}[S_n]$.
I understand that $\mathbb{E}[S_n] = n(1+N)/2$ because I managed to calculate it like this: I calculated the average of all possible sums I can get from $n$ different numbers from the numbers given:
$$\mathbb{E}[S_n] = \mathbb{E}[X_1] +\ldots + \mathbb{E}[X_n].$$
I managed only to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_1]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_2]$, but got stuck in $\mathbb{E}[X_3]$ and so on. I've tried to make an inductive statement but got lost trying to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_{i+1}]$.
I know that $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = (N+1)/2$ for every $i$, but I do not understand why. Why does each of $X_i$ have the same expected value? Why is $X_i \sim U(1,\dots,N)$ for $i>1$?

Each ball has an expected value of $\frac {N+1}2$, then just use linearity.  Keep in mind, Linearity does not require independence.

but why each ball has this expected value?

Each ball is equally likely to be drawn in any position.
